# Телефоны не звонят друг на друга(request timeout)

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, asterisk, voip

Установлены CentOS 7 + asterisk 13 + FreePBX 13 на виртуальной машине VirtualBox, софтфоны Microsip к астериску коннектятся, они онлайн и астериск их видит, но при попытке позвонить с одного на другой возникает ошибка 408. Не могу понять почему и как исправить..
Уже сделал:

1. Выключил FireWalld
2. Выключил iptables
3. Все равно на всякий случай открыл порты iptables.

tcpdump выводит следующее:

> IP 192.168.1.31.59472 > 192.168.1.52.sip: SIP, leight: 980
>
> IP 192.168.1.52 > 192.168.1.31: ICMP 192.168.1.52 udp port sip unreachable, leight 556

Адрес астериска: -.-.1.52

Адрес телефона: -.-.1.31

Что может быть не так?

Comment: Выяснил, что проблема с портом 5060, но почему? Я же задал его в iptables: iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 5060 -j ACCEPT

Comment: Возможно, файрволл на машине с софтфоном давит входящий трафик на порт 5060.

Comment: На машине с софтфоном стоит Win7, там порты 5060 тоже открыл.

Answer (score 0):

Банально, но сам астериск запущен? Порт слушается на сервере?

Выполните, чтобы проверить `netstat -nlpu | grep ':5060'`

Еще проверьте firewall в FreePBX 13